# Java, Map, как сравнить наличие всех ключ-значение в одной карте и в другой

Tags: java, map, сравнение

Есть две мапы:

```
general = {title=Cymbeline, year=1611, author=Shakespeare}
```

и

```
dictionary = {year=1611, author=Shakespeare}
```

Мне нужно, если каждое ключ-значение dictionary присутствует в general вернуть true, иначе false.

Помогите, пожалуйста, я всю голову сломал.

Comment: Чего там "ломать"... Получи список ключей в `dictionary`. Пройдись по ним в цикле и сравни значения тех ключей. Если что-то не совпадет - `false`. Иначе - `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам в точности нужно сравнивать каждую пару ключ-значение, то подойдёт вот такой вариант:

```
general.entrySet().containsAll(dictionary.entrySet())
```

Здесь мы проверяем, является ли множество пар второй мапы подмножеством пар первой мапы.

Пример:

```
Map<String, Object> general = Map.of(
    "title", "Cymbeline",
    "year", 1611,
    "author", "Shakespeare"
);
Map<String, Object> dictionary = Map.of(
    "year", 1611,
    "author", "Shakespeare"
);
System.out.println(general.entrySet().containsAll(dictionary.entrySet()));
```

Результат:

```
true
```

Если какую-нибудь из пар в `dictionary` поменять, или добавить новую пару, то в результате мы уже получим `false`, так как во множестве `general` такой пары не найдётся.

Comment: Огромное спасибо.